# running openai and langchain in AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, openai-api, langchain, aws-lambda-layers

I would like to use openai, langchain python libraries in aws lambda.
I created a lambda layer on my Mac using a simple shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up virtual environment
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate

# Install langchain library
pip install langchain
pip install openai
pip install pydantic-core

# Create layer directory structure
mkdir -p python/
cp -r myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/* python/

# Compress the layer directory
zip -r layer.zip python

# Clean up
deactivate
rm -rf myenv python

#run this file to create a layer
#./layer.sh
```

i uploaded it into aws but It failed because it could not load pydantic-core (that's the reason why I installed it with pip swell ). So I thought okay, maybe I need to create my layer on amazon linux. So i created I docker file with amazonlinux and tried to install python3.10 but I failed.

has someone faced similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved this issue. It appears that you may have used a Macbook M1 for the pip install process.
The solution involves not using a different runtime to build the layer file.

Use Docker to create an environment identical to that of your lambda function. For me, the issue is resolved.

If you use arm64 for lambda layer

```
docker pull arm64v8/ubuntu
docker run -it arm64v8/ubuntu
```

then create your layer file in docker
after that, copy to local and upload to aws lambda

```
docker cp {container_id}:{path_of_layer.zip} {local_path}
```